# blueimg jquery file upload - cannot delete uploaded images from server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, image

I am using blueimg jquery file upload Basic Plus UI version and it uploads image to server fine.

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Howver, then I click delete button to delete uploaded image(s), the image get deleted on screen, BUT not deleted from server directory where the images are.

When I refresh the screen all the uploaded images (regardless deleted or not) re-appear on the screen.

Could anyone tell me:
1. How to actually delete the images from server? (not just from web screen)
2. When I refresh the screen, do not show any loaded images, just clear the screen (re start upload process)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the UploadHandler.php class...

By default the method for deleting files is DELETE, but not all servers support this.
You can change it to POST by setting the $options parameter of the class constructor.

```
$foo = new UploadHandler(array('delete_type' => 'POST'));
```

See line 52 of UploadHandler.php

```
//Set the following option to 'POST', if your server does not support
//DELETE requests. This is a parameter sent to the client:
'delete_type' => 'DELETE',
```